# Rails Through relation and build

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this 3 simple models:

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user_conversation
   has_many :users, through: :user_conversation
end

class UserConversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :conversation
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belong_to :user_conversation
  has_many :conversations, through: :user_conversation
end
```

I want to insert some data in UserConversation by:

```
Conversation.find(params[:some_id]).users << User.where(id: [1,2,3])
```

The idea is append existing users to existing Conversation. 
When i do this by above command I get error:

```
ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute `user_conversation_id'
```

I suppose I have error in associations?

Comment: Are you implementing `N to N` relationship, if so, then your association declarations are wrong..

Comment: The `belong_to :user_conversation` associations on the `Conversation` and `User` model should be `has_many :user_conversations` instead.

Comment: You are right, I found my error. Thanks